# Chronon not showing up in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide

I just installed JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 and loaded my default (Maven) project, but Chronon is not showing up in Run/Debug configurations... Is there something special I have to do to enable it?

Comment: Ultimate or Community? Also check that you enabled the plugin (not enabled by default I think).

Comment: Community. The plugin is not available in the Plugins menu or in the Jetbrains repository. I tried installing it manually, but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it [only works in the Ultimate version](http://chrononsystems.com/blog/chronon-comes-to-intellij-idea-official-partnership-with-jetbrains):

> The Chronon plugin will ship as part of Intellij IDEA 13.1 Ultimate Edition.

Comment: Accepted as answer. However this is quite strange because on the [What's New](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/) page from IntelliJ IDEA it doesn't say anything about having to have the Ultimate version.

Answer (score 2):

Right, it only ships with Ultimate.

But even then, there's currently no support for applications run via Maven goals, according to http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/try-chronon-debugger-with-intellij-idea-13-1-eap/ where it states:

> Creating a Chronon support for Maven and / or GWT is another question. Feature request to (can't past another link) is welcome.

A search on Jetbrain's IJCP does not show such a feature request.

Note: I'm using Ultimate 13.1.2 and the "Run with Chronon" Button show up when a Maven-Runconfiguration is selected. But there's no debug configuration dialog/tab for Chronon in the Run/Debugconfiguration dialog.